# Decimal form of irrational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

In the decimal form of an irrational number like:
$$\pi=3.141592653589\ldots$$
Do we have all the numbers from $0$ to $9$. I verified $\pi$ and all the numbers are there. Is this true in general for irrational numbers ?

In other words, for an irrational number
$$x=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_n 10^n$$

Does $a_n$ takes all the numbers between $0$ and $9$ ?

Comment: [Here](http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/precalculated-frequencies) someone did the frequency counts for the decimal digits. Anyone knows a proof of the even distribution?

Comment: Let us crank this up to transcendental numbers. Any counter example?

Comment: @mvw The constant $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 10^{-i!}$ is transcendental because it is a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), but its decimal expansion contains only the digits $0$ and $1$.

Comment: That was quick. Thank you!

Comment: I see a potential problem with the accepted answer, depending on what you mean by "in general". The irrationals with all 10 digits represented are infinitely denser than those without. For example, consider the irrationals that have no 9s in their expansions. From each one, you can generate an infinitude of irrationals by inserting various counts of 9s in various places. So even though there are counterexamples, the proportion of their count is 0. So for some justifiable definition of "in general", the answer to your question is actually "Yes".

Comment: @MackTuesday Please elaborate this a bit and put it as a second answer, even if it is not accepted.

Comment: You might look at [normal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)  This is *much* more restrictive than what you ask, but "most" irrational numbers are normal.  Unfortunately, proving any given number normal is extremely difficult.

Comment: @RossMillikan -- AFAIK, all explicit examples of numbers that are *normal* (in some base $k$, say) are contrived by referring to base-$k$ representations in their definition (e.g., by concatenation of base-$k$ numerals). This suggests an analogy: **Is there any explicit example of an *irrational* that does not contain all $k$ digits (in some base $k$), whose definition does not refer to base-$k$ representations?** (By "explicit example", I mean one for which an algorithm is provided to compute the digits; i.e., the digits can actually be listed.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Certainly not, since rational numbers are exactly the ones with an eventually periodic expansion. So for example, the number $0.01001100011100001111\ldots$ is irrational.

Answer (score 9):

"Almost every" real number has every digit from $0$ to $9$, in the sense that the set of real numbers that do not has Lebesgue measure $0$.

To show this, it suffices (by countable additivity of the measure) to show that the set of real numbers *between 0 and 1* that do not contain every digit has measure zero.  In turn it suffices by additivity of the measure to show that the set of real numbers between 0 and 1 *with no $9$s* has measure $0$.
Call this set $S$.

Consider a decimal expansion $0.a_1a_2a_3 \ldots$.
The set of real numbers for which $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_{k-1} \ne 9$ and $a_k = 9$, call it $E_k$, is measurable and has measure exactly $9^{k-1} \cdot \frac{1}{10^k}$.
A real number has the digit $9$ in this decimal expansion if and only if it is not in $E_k$ for any $k$, and the $E_k$ are disjoint.  Thus,
$$
\mu([0,1] \setminus S)
= \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right)
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{9^{k-1} }{10^k} = 1
$$
and $S$ has measure $0$ as desired.

Comment: Note the similarity between removing intervals of real numbers containing 9s and constructing the [Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Answer (score 6):

You ask whether the property you describe is true "in general for irrational numbers". That phrase can mean "all irrational numbers", or "most irrational numbers". Because you have accepted Geoffrey's answer of "Certainly not...", I guess you mean "all".

However, to be clear, I want to give treatment to "most" because the answer to that question is "Yes..."

Consider an irrational number like

$$x = 0.1280451740318436570487162...$$

that contains no 9s. We'll call such numbers *9-less*. From this single number, many 9-*full* irrationals can be created simply by inserting 9s in various places.

$x$ is non-terminating. Therefore, there is an infinitude of possible insertion points, which means an infinitude of 9-full irrationals can be generated in this way. (In fact, it can be shown that the set is [uncountable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).)

Each 9-less irrational generates a *distinct* infinite set of 9-full irrationals. Therefore, the ratio of 9-less irrationals to 9-full irrationals is zero.

Every irrational number is either 9-less or 9-full, but not both, so [almost all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) irrational numbers are 9-full.

Addendum:

As you will find in the Wikipedia article, "almost all" has several different uses. In this case it means 9-less numbers have [Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) 0. In other words, they're "sprinkled" among the irrationals, no two "touching". It also means that if you pick an irrational number at random (from a finite interval), it has probability 0 of being 9-less, and probability 1 of being 9-full. This is *despite* the fact that both sets have the same size, or [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). Such is the weirdness of infinities.

Further addendum:

There's another proof of this involving the probability of selecting an infinite sequence of digits randomly and never getting a 9.

Comment: By the way, some of the assertions I make here can be made stronger, and the argument will still be valid.

Comment: There are uncountably many 9-less numbers too, though I think the set has Lebesgue measure zero. Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "almost all".

Comment: I think this answer is good intuition, but dangerously nonrigorous.

Comment: You've shown that given a 9-less number, we can generate uncountably many 9-full numbers.  So what?  Given a 9-full number, I can also easily generate uncountably many 9-less numbers.  And your procedure for generating 9-full numbers isn't even injective, i.e. distinct 9-less numbers may give the same 9-full number.

Comment: From a set-theoretic point of view, the cardinality of the set of 9-lees numbers is just as huge as the cardinality of all irrational numbers, that is $2^{\aleph_0}$. So wrt. set cardinality, the partition of all irrational numbers into the 9-less numbers and the non-9-less number is a partition into to equinumerous sets. So what do you mean by "almost all" here? You are maybe referring to some _measure_, like the Lebesgue measure or some probability measure. You should make that much more explicit. In short, @Goos is right.

Comment: Clearly my understanding isn't very mature, but @Goos, can you provide an example of two distinct 9-less numbers giving the same 9-full number? I can't see it. It would seem that inserting 9s into each couldn't change the fact that they differ.

Comment: Regarding "Lebesgue measure zero" and "almost none", I thought the first was a special case of the second. Am I wrong about that? Or maybe you're saying I'm not wrong, just too imprecise? Would it help to talk about density instead? Obviously I need some guidance here. In fact, I'll readily delete everything I've said if people think it's a good idea.

Comment: Please keep this answer. It's correct and sufficiently rigorous (using links rather than explaining basic terms like "almost all").

Comment: @Charles "correct and sufficiently rigorous?"  This answer seems to be an attempt to show that the 9-full numbers cross product an uncountable set are equal in cardinality to the 9-less numbers.  But with both sets being uncountable, you can hardly derive that almost all irrational numbers are 9-full.  Moreover, the Wikipedia page for "almost all" contains several definitions before the probably intended "almost every", and this answer makes no attempt to do any measure theory.

Comment: @Goos, switching isn't allowed -- I think? MackTuesday says "insertion".

Comment: @senderle I see now: *inserting* 9s, not replacing 9s.

Comment: @MackTuesday I misunderstood your answer, and thought you were replacing digits with 9s.

Comment: @Goos: I don't think that's accurate at all! It acknowledges that the cardinalities are the same (well, or at least that they're uncountable) but that almost all (in the technical sense) have all 10 digits. That's perfectly correct.

Comment: @MackTuesday Lebesgue measure zero is one definition of "almost none" but certainly not the only one. The page you linked gives other definitions for "almost all" like "all but a countable set" which do not apply, so it would help if you clarified which definition does apply.

Comment: @MackTuesday What Goos is trying to say is that there are just as many ways to generate infinitely many 9-ful numbers from 9-less numbers as there are 9-less numbers from 9-ful numbers, since cardinality-wise, there are equal numbers of both.

Since $2^{\aleph_0} \cdot \aleph_0 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ there is a mapping so that for every 9-ful number there are infinitely many 9-less numbers.

Comment: I will show that there are "equal" numbers of 9-ful and 9-less below:

For example, let $f(x)$ take a 9-less number $x$ as an argument and return the reinterpretation of that number as it it were in base 9. Except for a countable set, all values of $f(x)$ are unique. So the inverse $f^{-1}(x)$ is defined for _almost all_ values.

Now for almost all 9-ful numbers $x$ calculate $f^{-1}(x)$ and we have a one-to-one mapping. Since the cardinality is uncountable, the countable set does not affect the cardinality. Hence we prove there is a 9-less number for every 9-ful number and vice versa.

Comment: The point about cardinality is well taken. Now let's say we fairly pick a random number between 0 and 1. The probability of selecting an irrational number is 1. Do we agree that the probability of selecting a 9-full number is also 1? If so I can add an erratum/addendum.

Comment: @MackTuesday You are correct. This is because the set of 9-less numbers has Lebesgue measure zero, which you are using as your definition of "almost none". To avoid confusing readers, it is useful to explicitly state that this definition is being used, since "almost all/none" is an ambiguous phrase.

Comment: I've amended and revised the answer. Please let me know if any further corrections are needed.

Answer (score 1):

This gives a nice opportunity to use cardinality arguments to show that the answer is negative.

Pick two digits $n,k$ such that $\{n,k\}\neq\{0,9\}$. There is a bijection between the numbers in $[0,1]$ whose decimal form includes only $n$ and $k$, and the set of infinite binary sequences.

Therefore the set $\{x\in[0,1]\mid x\text{ has only }n,k\text{ as decimal digits}\}$ is uncountable. So it must include at least one irrational number, and in fact almost the entire set is made of irrational numbers.

The same can be done with three, four, five, six, seven, eight or nine digits. The argument is just the same. Alternatively one can use diagonalization to show that the set is uncountable, it's the same method as you would use otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that there are "irrational numbers" which their decimal expansion does not include all digits but some of them

There is also [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) which is studied in Number Theory

i think there is a theorem that on average the probability of each digit in the set of irrational numbers is equiprobable with probability one (ie almost everywhere)
And this is related to equidistribution theorems

(Answer by [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/806591/139391) provides a short proof of the above statement)

Please correct if i am mistaken here